# Java: Swap two rows of 3-dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
int[][][] D = new int[N][M][2];
```

My question is: how can I swap `D[N][M][0]` and `D[N][M][1]` (it is NOT swap two elements, but swap whole array). It maybe seems silly, but I cannot imagine how 3-dimensional array organize, so I don't know which is the best method to copy it. Moreover, I don't sure does `D[N][M][0]` and `D[N][M][1]` is two block consecutive in memory ? If not, so I should do that:

```
int[][][] D = new int[2][N][M]
```

right ?

Thanks :)

Comment: As written D[N][M][0] is an int element, not an array.  So you are asking to swap two ints, I believe.

Comment: @BlackVegetable No.I have noted that copy whole array, not single element. But I don't really know how to write it clearly. Can you fix my post ?

Comment: As Aleksander Gralak answered, you want to omit the last `[0]` as it indicates a particular index of that final array.  You want D[A][B] to be switched not an element within D[A][B].

Comment: No you do not have to copy one by one. Look at my answer. Each element in multidimensional array is just a reference to the array which is one dimension smaller. At the end when you have only one dimension, then you have real values.

Comment: @AleksanderGralak I think you confused me with another poster.  I never proposed switching one by one.  In fact, I agree with you.

Comment: @BlackVegetable you are right. Sorry for this. I have already fixed my previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D[N][M][0]` is just a single `int`. The whole row is under this reference `D[N][M]`, so to swap rows do this:

```
int[] tmp = D[N][M];
D[N][M] = D[N][M+1];
D[N][M+1] = tmp;
```

Comment: Just make sure that M+1 is not out of the bounds of the array. (+1)